# FTP authentification access via rest API

Tags: rest-api, integration, ftp, dataloader.io

A third company provide me with an ftp host username, passwd and port to access some data.

If I enter to the ftp via web browser I can access just putting user and passwd.

If I try to enter via rest api or dataloader.io or filezilla I cant get in.

What could be the problem? (First time trying to do this type of integration)

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FTP protocol is a binary protocol that involves two "ports" (a command port and data port), and is also meant to be an interactive protocol. Apex code and other REST-based calls can't access this, as you need the HTTP protocol in order for it to work. The usual solution is to deploy a FTP proxy (an HTTP-based server that can call FTP commands). This will require a third-party service outside of Salesforce in order to work.